# Put Gif Image Into Some Frame (Box)

Tags: c#, imagemagick, gif, magick.net, imagemagick.net

I am generating gif animation from existing images using magic.net Magick.NET library. It's working well. Now, what I am trying to achieve is to put the generated gif into some box, frame like in the picture below.
So the gif to be animated inside this pic.

One way could be to apply this frame to each existing photo and then generate the final gif which is working now. But Can I apply it directly to gif and still maintain the animation?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you just try it..?

Comment: try putting the image in the frame that's what..

Comment: Did you read the question?! I tried and did it. Now, I want to achieve that same goal through different approach which is to apply frame to the final result only!!!

Comment: Read the FAQ for how to use downvote. And explain it too please

Comment: individuals on here can downvote for numerous reasons. anyway I think that your last part is a bit hard to understand.. sorry for the misunderstanding .